# With the Twilio API is there a way to get the date when the first phone was verified?

Tags: rest, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to get this data from Twilio

- When do they verify/provision first caller Id
- When the first call is made after the confirmation, and the result & duration

I'm looking at the Docs but I can't find a way other than make a request to the calls endpoint and iterate through the result. This is not ideal because in some cases could be quite a big request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio API is pretty focused on most recent logs rather than looking back to the start. However you might be able to make this slightly easier on yourself and the API.

First up, you can list all the [incoming phone numbers and find the oldest among that list](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers).

Then you can take that number, get it's `date_created` value and use that to start searching for the first call it made. You can then use [list filters on the call resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/call#list-filters) to search for calls from that number that started on the created date. If you don't find any, you can start iterating the date a day onwards at a time until you find the first call resources.

Let me know if that helps at all.